# Handle popup messages - Coded UI Test

Tags: c#, testing, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

### Issue

---

I am running tests using the Coded UI Test builder and writing all the code from scratch. The issue I am facing is in the middle of the test there is a popup message with the results "Stay on this page" or "Leave this page". I want my test to be able to click "Stay on this page".

The popup sometimes appears straight after the event or sometimes appears a couple of seconds later.

### Code

---

So the event that I run before the message appears is a button click:

```
ClickButton(browser, "login");

void ClickButton(UITestControl parent, string id)
{
    var button = new HtmlButton(parent);
    button.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlButton.PropertyNames.Id, id);

    Mouse.Click(button);
}
```

I have tried `Keyboard.SendKeys()` but this just sends the keys to the browser window. I have also tried using the recording tool. Both are unsuccessful.

After this event I need to wait for the popup to appear and click "Stay on this page". Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

We actually mapped this confirmation window and it works for us.
We start with a Window with name = Windows Internet Explorer
Followed by a Pane with name = Windows Internet Explorer
and finally with a Button of name Stay on this page

All with Technology = MSAA.

You must handle writing code to wait for readiness of the control and proper time out if you don't expect the confirmation every time.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Would you be able to give me a small example of the code for this? I am a bit confused reading it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly that window is, you should be able to deal with it no problem.  I would use the inspector to get the properties of the window and use one of the WaitFor* methods to give it some time.  Here is an example of dealing with the security pop up that IE shows:

```
namespace CaptainPav.Testing.UI.CodedUI.PageModeling.Win
{
    public class IESecurityWindow<T> : PageModelBase<WinWindow>
     {
        protected const string SecurityWindowName = "Internet Explorer Security";

        internal protected override WinWindow Me => new WinWindow().Extend(WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name, SecurityWindowName, PropertyExpressionOperator.EqualTo);

        protected WinButton AllowButton => this.Me.Find<WinButton>(WinButton.PropertyNames.Name, "Allow", PropertyExpressionOperator.EqualTo);

        internal readonly T AllowModel;
        public IESecurityWindow(T allowModel)
        {
            this.AllowModel = allowModel;
        }

        public T ClickAllow()
        {
            // if not IE, this will return false and the next model is returned; change the time if you need more or less wait
            if (this.AllowButton.IsActionable(3000))
            {
                Mouse.Click(this.AllowButton);
            }

            return AllowModel;
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, the dialog is a Win* type, not Html*.  There are some custom extension methods sprinkled in to make the searching and stuff easier, but this should give you an idea.  If interested, the extensions (which are written by me) can be found on [github](https://github.com/spelltwister/CodedUIFluentExtensions).